# getting problem solving Linear Finite-Difference using matlab

Tags: matlab, math

i'm trying to solve this problem using this algorithm and i try matrix and normal way to solve it but i cant!
[Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxda7.png)

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYEpy.png)

can anyone help where is the mistake in this code? Thanks,

This code without using the matrix as in the algorithm :

```
clc;
clear;

p=@(x) -2/x;
q=@(x) 2/(x^2);
r=@(x) sin(log(x))/(x^2);
x=1;
a0=1;
a=1;
b=2;
N=9;
%Step 1
h=(b-a)/N;
A=zeros(N,N);
B=zeros(N,1);
a(1)=2+(h^2)*q(x(1));
b(1)=-1+(h/2)*p(x(1));
d(1)=-(h^2)*r(x(1))+(1+(h/2))*p(x(1))*a0;
%Step 2
for i=2:N-1
    x=a+i*h;
    a(i)=2+(h^2)*q(x(i));
    b(i)=-1+(h/2)*p(x(i));
    c(i)=-1-(h/2)*p(x(i));
    d(i)=-(h^2)*r(x(i));
end
%Step 3
x=b-h;
a(N)=2+(h^2)*q(x(i));
c(N)=-1-(h/2)*p(x(i));
d(N)=-(h^2)*r(x(i));
%Step 4
I(1)=a(1);
u(1)=d(1)/a(1);
z(1)=d(1)/I(1);
%Step 5
for i=2:N-1
    I(i)=a(i)-c(i)*u(i-1);
    u(i)=b(i)/I(i);
    z(i)=(d(i)-c(i)*z(i-1))/I(i);
end
%Step 6
I(N)=a(N)-c(N)*u(N-1);
z(N)=(d((N)-c(N)*z(N-1))/I(N);
%Step 7
%w(0)=alpha;
w(N+1)=beta;
w(N)=z(N);
%Step 8
for i=N-1:1
    w(i)=z(i)-u(i)*w(i+1);
end
%Step 9
for i=0:N+1
    x=a+i*h;
end
disp(x,w(i))
```

**And this one with using matrix but not completed, the MATLAB give me errors:**

```
p(x)=-2/x;
q(x)=2/(x^2);
r(x)=sin(log(x))/(x^2);
a0=1;
a=1;
b=2;
N=9;
h=(b-a)/N
A=zeros(N,N);
B=zeros(N,1);
A(1,1)=2+(h^2)*q(x(1));
A(1,2)=-1+(h/2)*p(x(1));
B(1)=-(h^2)*r(x(1))+(1+(h/2))*p(x(1))*a0;
for i=2:N-1
    x=a+i*h;
    A(i,i-1)=2+(h^2)*q(x(i));
    A(i,i)=-1+(h/2)*p(x(i));
    A(i,i+1)=-1-(h/2)*p(x(i));
    B(i)=-(h^2)*r(x(i));
end
x=b-h;
A(N,N-1)=2+(h^2)*q(x(i));
A(N,N+1)=-1-(h/2)*p(x(i));
B(N)=-(h^2)*r(x(i));

I(1,1)=A(1,1);
U(1,1)=A(1,2)/A(1,1);
Z(1,1)=B(1)/I(1,1);

for i=2:N-1
    I(i,i)=A(i,i-1)-A(i,i+1)*U(i,i);
    U(i,i)=A(i,i)/I(i,i);
    Z(i,i)=(B(i)-A(i,i+1)*Z(i,i-1))/I(i,i);
end
I(1,1)
```

Comment: There are quite a few errors in both codes. You should read the algorithm more carefully. For example, in step 3 you use `x(i)` but it should be `x(N)` and your for loop in step 8 will not iterate through all the indices. Once you have addressed those, ask specific questions about one code, not both.

Comment: Thanks @David, but how i can declare the function p(x)=-2/x;
q(x)=2/(x^2);
r(x)=sin(log(x))/(x^2); correctly ? Thanks,

Comment: Use anonymous functions.